# Why isn't clearInterval() stopping the setInterval function?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a snake game and the entire game is ran inside of the `runGame()` function. I have the function set to repeat every 80ms like this `startGame = setInterval(runGame, 80)` Then inside of the `runGame()` function I check for a collision. Inside the the `checkForCollision()` function I set a timeout to return true after 5 seconds indicating there has been a collision then running the code
`clearInterval(runGame)` this does nothing? Why is that?

```js
//grab the canvas/set its context/create the snake and its size
const cvs = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const unit = 16;
const snake = [
    {
    //set the snakes starting position in the middle of the canvas
    x: cvs.width/2 - 8,
    y: cvs.height/2 - 8
    }
];
let food = {x: 0, y: 0}

let startGame = setInterval(rungame, 80);
getFood();

let direction;
function rungame() {
    isRunning = true;
    draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "limegreen");

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode == 37) direction = "left";
        else if(event.keyCode == 38) direction = "up";
        else if(event.keyCode == 39) direction = "right";
        else if(event.keyCode == 40) direction = "down";
    });

    
    
    
    switch(direction) {
        case "left":
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "#858585");
            snake[0].x -= unit
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "limegreen");
            break;
        case "right":
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "#858585");
            snake[0].x += unit
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "limegreen");
            break;
        case "up":
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "#858585");
            snake[0].y -= unit
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "limegreen");
            break;
        case "down":
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "#858585");
            snake[0].y += unit
            draw(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, "limegreen");
            break;         
    }

    if(checkForCollision()) clearInterval(startGame);
}

//--------------------HELPER FUNCTIONS
function draw(x, y, color) {
    for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, unit, unit, color);
    }
}

function getFood() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cvs.width/unit) * unit;
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * cvs.height/unit) * unit;
    food.x = x;
    food.y = y;
    draw(food.x, food.y, 'red');
}

function checkForCollision() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return true;
    }, 5000)
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Odibee Sans';
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #333;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -27.5px;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #858585;
}

.score {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    align-self: center;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-shadow:  5px 0px 0px #858585;
    /* why does align self work here but not justify-content */
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Snake 2.0</title>  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Odibee+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="score">0</div>
        <div class="canvas-wrap">
            <canvas width="1008" height="528"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: because `checkForCollision` itself doesn't return `true`. The callback function returns true instead. Currently it returns `undefined`, which is considered falsy

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `checkForCollision` function is returning `undefined` so the condition never is `true`, you just executing the function inside the timer and the returning value is never passed to the outter function to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return from an`async` function, the `setTimeout` is an async function. The `checkForCollision` function will always return `undefined`.

**Solution:**

Return a `promise` from the`checkForCollision` function.

```
function checkForCollision() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true);
  }, 5000)
  });
}
```

And wait for the promise to be resolved.

```
(async function() {
  let  collision = await checkForCollision();
  if(collision);
    clearInterval(startGame);
})();
```